# Match whole word in a string without accidental matches

Tags: php, regex, validation, parsing, preg-match

Parsing an array of string commands, I need to know if a string contains a specific keyword.

Sounds simple I know, but the problem comes when the command keyword may also be part of another word.

Ex:

```
CHECKSOUND
SOUND
CHECK
```

So I need to check if the current line has the CHECKSOUND, SOUND, or CHECK command.

If I use something like:

```
if(stristr($line,'SOUND') == true)
```

Then it may find `CHECKSOUND` before `SOUND` and thus not parse correctly.

**Question**:

Is there a way to find only an occurrence of a whole word like SOUND and ignore the occurrence SOUND if found as part of another word like CHECKSOUND?

I am sure I am missing something simple here.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to easily achive the goal.

Example #2 from the documentation of [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
/* The \b in the pattern indicates a word boundary, so only the distinct
 * word "web" is matched, and not a word partial like "webbing" or "cobweb" */
 if (preg_match("/\bweb\b/i", "PHP is the web scripting language of choice.")) {
     echo "A match was found.";
 } else {
     echo "A match was not found.";
 }
```

Note that the above example uses the `i` modifier, which makes the search for "web" case insensitive.