# PHP strpos - search only full words

Tags: php, strpos

If I have a string containing the word **Company** and I wish to search for only full words, such as **any**, I encounter a problem using strpos(), as follows:

```
if (strpos($desc, $row['phrase']) !== false )
{
    // action
}
```

This script will return TRUE because **Company** contains a substring: **any** which is unhelpful because the script needs to detect only full words.

*The company is working*

doesn't contain the word: **any**

but

*Is there **any** change*

does contain the word: "any". How may I edit a strpos function to search only full words, i.e. not part of them?

Thanks.

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325956/how-to-find-a-whole-word-in-a-string-in-php-without-accidental-matches

Comment: Words are usually split by spaces so.... `strpos($desc, " " . $row['phrase'] . " ")`

Comment: @slevy1 why do you think that duplicate is wrong. It uses \b which is word

Comment: @slevy1 no he is not! It's strpos !== False . It has nothing to do with the position. Read the manual about strpos

Comment: @Andreas, so the sentence `This world is a nice place.` doesn't contain the words `place` or `this`? Because your code wouldn't catch it...

Comment: @walther you mean the strpos from comment above or the answer below?

Comment: @Andreas, I mean the comment above, as it expects you to split the sentences using spaces only, which clearly isn't the case in the real world. We have commas, exclamation marks etc. Your answer below looks correct though (using \b instead of spaces).

Comment: @walther sometimes a low tech solution as spaces is all that is needed. It's not enough for an answer but it may solve his problem. If you know there is no `. ,` in the string then that will be enough.

Comment: For those of you who'd like to see this topic "reopened", check this out:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44532672/php-how-to-properly-use-strpos-to-find-a-word-in-a-string?noredirect=1#comment76057936_44532672

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex.

https://regex101.com/r/Evd3iF/1

```
$re = '/\b[Aa]ny\b/';
$str = 'Company any any. Any, ';

If(preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0)){
        //string contains word
 }

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

The word to pattern can be made with

```
$pattern = "/\b[" . strtoupper(Substr($word,0,1)) . strtolower(Substr($word,0,1)) . "]" . Substr($word,1);
```

Please note I wrote this answer on my phone, so I may have made a mistake in the above pattern