# PHP: How to Properly Use Strpos() to Find a Word in a String

Tags: php, string, strpos

If one is experienced in PHP, then one knows how to find whole words in a string and their position using a regex and preg_match() or preg_match_all.  But, if you're looking instead for a lighter solution, you may be tempted to try with strpos().  The question emerges as to how one can use this function without it detecting substrings contained in other words.  For example, how to detect "any" but not those characters occurring in "company"?

Consider a string like the following:

```
"Will *any* company do *any* job, (are there any)?"
```

How would one apply strpos() to detect each appearance of "any" in the string? Real life often involves more than merely space delimited words. Unfortunately, this sentence didn't appear with the non-alphabetical characters when I originally posted.

Comment: That's what regular expressions were designed for.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense.  `strpos()` will *always* detect the position of the string you supply.  If that's not what you want, don't use it.

Comment: If you're being pedantic about the use of `strpos` and only want `any` as a word on it's own, just use a space before and after the word, and add one to the resulting index.

Comment: It may come across as misguided, but there may be a utility for someone who needs to squeeze out just a little more performance. Please don't downvote due the YAGNI consideration, this is not a bad question.

Comment: @fubar - thanks for the feedback. Please take a look now at my question.

Comment: @ Jared Farrish, thank you!

Comment: I downvoted because I believe the question is unanswerable.  He is asking how to "*apply strpos()*" to do something it simply doesn't do.  No amount of modifying the source string or iterations will change that.  If in fact the desired result is achieved by doing so, you are right back to it not being a function of `strpos()` and (probably) could have gotten better performance by simply using a regex.  To me this question is like asking, "How can I use the `==` operator to do strict comparison, because == gets better performance than ==="

Comment: @ billynoa, she (that's me) is asking how to apply strpos().  My answer shows 2 ways to accomplish this feat in tandem with other PHP functions. You may prefer to use a regex but for those regex-adverse I've shown *how* one may use strpos().  You may dislike my question but to downvote it is to attempt to restrict options (knowledge) to only that which meet your approval.  Furthermore, the truth will out no matter how much you may downvote my thoughts.  As it turns out, the truth can't be voted out of existence unless one is living in a tyranny where only the sanctioned ideas are permitted.

Comment: @slevy1 - sorry for assuming you were a "he".  I don't dislike your question, I just don't see how it makes sense.  I offered up my reason for downvoting (something not many people will bother with) on the off chance that some convincing argument would emerge to change my mind.  the comment you just made doesn't really get me there.  but good luck and hope you found what you were looking for in the answers here.

Comment: @billynoah - I think the point was, how to incorporate a function using `strpos()` that obviates the need for a regex. That is 100% answerable. And in fact was fun as a thought experiment.

Comment: @JaredFarrish If it is performance that is the goal then it's not as easy as regex is slow strpos is fast. Since this question is a "breakout" from a different question I just use the code from the previous question. Here is the regex performance https://3v4l.org/rpP0o/perf#output and here is stros https://3v4l.org/IiVYk/perf#output the odd thing is that if we make the regex simpler with `'/\bany\b/'` the code runs quite significantly slower https://3v4l.org/SXAau/perf#output . With that in mind I think, if you really want to focus on performance you need to look at each part individually.

Comment: @Andreas - The definition of "heavier" and "lighter" is debatable as to what that might mean. Performance is obviously what most would think of, but I choose to ignore that, since there is some variability about how it would be implemented. YMMV.

Comment: @Jared Farrish: heavier == slower and lighter == faster.  And, per the Manual: Tip
Do not use preg_match() if you only want to check if one string is contained in another string. Use strpos() instead as it will be faster." A regex is most useful if you use a pattern to detect an unknown such as a domain name -- see http://www.php.net/preg_match.  While it seems easier to just use a regex with a preg_ function, for optimal performance using strpos even tho' it may involve writing more code may be more efficient.

Comment: I'm not getting into performance of this or that. I know regexes are slow. I also use them all the time for all kinds of things (simple ones) and not once have I ever had a performance issue. YMMV.

Comment: For what it's worth, to satisfy my own curiosity, I put @slevy1's accepted answer alongside Jared Farrish's and good ol `preg_match_all()` to see how they performed. the comparison is admittedly a bit unfair since Jared's function only returns the first position while the other two get all matches and positions.  The results were as follows for 1 million iterations of each: `firstWordPosition()` took **1.067** seconds, slevy's answer: **8.977** seconds, `preg_match_all()` **0.905** seconds.

Comment: Interesting article with respect to androids: http://www.androidauthority.com/beware-of-the-benchmarks-604989/ and may have some applicability beyond those devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$subject = "any";
$b = " ";
$delimited = "$b$subject$b";

$replace = array("?","*","(",")",",",".");
$str = "Will *any* company do *any* job, (are there any)?";
echo "\nThe string: \"$str\"";

$temp = str_replace($replace,$b,$str);
while ( ($pos = strpos($temp,$delimited)) !== false )
{
    echo "\nThe subject \"$subject\" occurs at position ",($pos + 1);
    for ($i=0,$max=$pos + 1 + strlen($subject); $i <= $max; $i++) {
        $temp[$i] = $b;
    }
}
```

See [demo](https://3v4l.org/IiVYk#output)

The script defines a word boundary as a blank space. If the string has non-alphabetical characters, they are replaced with blank space and the result is stored in `$temp`. As the loop iterates and detects `$subject`, each of its characters changes into a space in order to locate the next appearance of the subject.  Considering the amount of work involved one may wonder if such effort really pays off compared to using a regex with a preg_ function.  That is something that one will have to decide themselves.  My purpose was to show *how* this may be achieved using strpos() without resorting to the oft repeated conventional wisdom of SO which advocates using a regex.

There is an option if you are loathe to create a replacement array of non-alphabetical characters, as follows:

```
<?php

function getAllWholeWordPos($s,$word){
  $b = " ";
  $delimited = "$b$word$b";
  $retval = false;

  for ($i=0, $max = strlen( $s ); $i < $max; $i++) {
          if ( !ctype_alpha( $s[$i] ) ){
              $s[$i] = $b;
          }
  }

 while ( ( $pos = stripos( $s, $delimited) ) !== false ) {
    $retval[] = $pos + 1;
    for ( $i=0, $max = $pos + 1 + strlen( $word ); $i <= $max; $i++) {
        $s[$i] = $b;
    }
 }
 return $retval;
}

$whole_word = "any";    
$str = "Will *$whole_word* company do *$whole_word* job, (are there $whole_word)?";

echo "\nString: \"$str\""; 

$result = getAllWholeWordPos( $str, $whole_word );
$times = count( $result );
echo "\n\nThe word \"$whole_word\" occurs $times times:\n";
foreach ($result as $pos) { 
   echo "\nPosition: ",$pos;
}
```

See [demo](https://3v4l.org/ZEoZe#output)

Note, this example with its update improves the code by providing a function which uses a variant of strpos(), namely stripos() which has the added benefit of being case insensitive.  Despite the more labor-intensive coding, the performance is speedy; see [performance](https://3v4l.org/ZEoZe/perf#output).

Comment: "lighter" here is totally in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: Thanks, but everyone working with PHP knows that the preg_ functions are heavier than using strpos().

Comment: Yes, and I'm sure that's to the distraction of every other consideration.

Comment: What about `-`, `[`, `]`, `'`, `"`, `#`, `~`, `|`, `_`, `@`, etc... Are you going to find and replace every single non alpha-numeric character?

Comment: @fubar - It's arguable whether someone sees some of those as "whitespace", so having some control might be useful.

Comment: I see your point although I've seen in real life very large PHP arrays, so it's feasible to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could probably just remove all the whitespace characters you care about (e.g., what about hyphenations?) and test for `" word "`:

```
var_dump(firstWordPosition('Will company any do any job, (are there any)?', 'any'));
var_dump(firstWordPosition('Will *any* company do *any* job, (are there any)?', 'any'));

function firstWordPosition($str, $word) {
    // There are others, maybe also pass this in or array_merge() for more control.
    $nonchars = ["'",'"','.',',','!','?','(',')','^','$','#','\n','\r\n','\t',];
    // You could also do a strpos() with an if and another argument passed in.
    // Note that we're padding the $str to with spaces to match begin/end.
    $pos = stripos(str_replace($nonchars, ' ', " $str "), " $word ");

    // Have to account for the for-space on " $str ".
    return $pos ? $pos - 1: false;
}
```

Gives 12 (offset from 0)

https://3v4l.org/qh9Rb

Comment: I'm curious as to why you have `" $word "` in the `stripos`? You're adding leading and trailing spaces? This will throw every index off by one.

Comment: Have you see the edit? The replace doesn't account for "Any of these", which it would miss.

Comment: Oh right, yeah, the purpose is to account for the boundary condition, e.g. " word ".

Comment: Yeah, sorry just figured that. And you're adding spaces to the string, because you're looking for the word with space boundaries. Got it.

Answer (score -2):

Try the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
echo strpos("I love php, I love php     too!","php");
?> 

</body>
</html>


Output: 7
```